# Pandas Dataframe to BigQuery raises NotImplementedError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

I've been trying for a while now to upload data from a Pandas DataFrame to a BigQuery table but I keep running into new issues.

I'm taking the following steps:

1. Calling data from an API and I'm assigning the response to a
   variable called: `result[]` . This variable is a list of nested
   dictionaries.
2. To convert this list of nested dictionaries into a dataframe I use the following command (with '_' separation: `new_df = json_normalize(result, sep='_')`
3. The result looks good and it seems the dataframe is created correctly with the following info (see point 4)
4. > class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'RangeIndex: 833 entries, 0 to 832
   >   Columns: 137 entries, card_billing_addr1 to subscription_updated_at
   >   dtypes: bool(4), float64(17), int64(17), object(99)
   >   memory usage: 868.9+ KB
5. Now it's time to upload the DataFrame to BigQuery, instead of using the pandas-gbq tool I'm using the [official cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration) and try to upload the DataFrame by using the following lines of code:

```
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_ref = client.dataset('dataset_name')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('table_name')

client.load_table_from_dataframe(new_df, table_ref).result()
```

After that I keep getting the error:

```
NotImplementedError: struct<key_1: string, key_2: string, ..., key_n: int64,>
```

I have no clue where to start to solve this. Does anyone have a fix or maybe a better suggestion on how to approach this?

Comment: The `json_normalizer` from pandas flattens the data (so nested structs becomes flat rows); if your table schema is structured to receive `structs` then it will break indeed.  Maybe you could try uploading `result` directly to BQ instead of casting it as dataframe before.

Comment: good point, the only reason I was using pandas is because I thought I needed to get everything in table format before uploading. Right now I'm writing the `result` directly into a JSON file with `with open('data.json', 'w') as fp: json.dump(result, fp)` however, uploading the file in BQ leads to the error _Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse JSON: No object found when new array is started.;_ any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Looks like some mistake happened during the `json.dump` step. Maybe try creating a new file with just the first row of `'data.json'` and try to debug from there.

Comment: Could you add the error's traceback?

Comment: The issue with this error: _No object found when new array is started._ is because Google bigquery only accepts **Newline Delimited JSON** and not an array of JSON documents. The trick here is to convert the data to NDJSON although that's where I'm stuck now as the documentation on the existing libraries for this is a bit unclear.

Comment: @WillianFuks You deserve to get voted the right answer! Basically your first comment was correct on a struct breaking the upload. When you serialise all structs it uploads fine. Alternatively you can upload as a newline delimited JSON but this will result into a bq table with structs in there and that was not the goal. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Sounds cool :). About having structs in your table, this can be used as a very effective design pattern for your data, specially if you combine with arrays (this can decrease considerably size of data being stored, queried and billed in your projects).